# Proving the impossibility of a particular binary sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\Omega = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$.

My question is as follows. Can there exist an $\omega \in \Omega$ such that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \omega_{k+a} = \frac{1}{2} \qquad \forall{a} \in \mathbb{N}$$
where $\omega_i \in \{0,1\}$ is the $i^{th}$ element of $\omega$?

This question comes from an exercise in probability theory which goes as follows.
Consider the events $$F_{\alpha} = \left\{\omega: \frac{\#(k\leq n: \omega_{\alpha(k)} = 1)}{n} \to \frac{1}{2}\right\}$$
where $\alpha \in A$ and $A = \{\alpha: \alpha: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, \alpha(1)< \alpha(2) < \ldots\}$. Then it holds that $\cap_{\alpha \in A}F_\alpha = \emptyset$.

I arrived at the question at the top by considering only the mappings $A = \{\alpha: \alpha: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}, \alpha(k) = k + a, a \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Any help/hint is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just take $\omega_i$ to be alternating between $0$ and $1$.

The trick for the actual exercise is that for every sequence $\alpha$ that satisfies the condition, you can find a subsequence $\alpha'$ where every $\omega_{\alpha'(k)}$ is zero.

Comment: Thank you for the example. About the actual exercise, that subsequence is an element of $A$ and along that subsequence the limit is $0$, right?